# What is the name for a natural transformation that has both lax and oplax monoidal properties?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal C,\mathcal D,\mathcal E$ be monoidal categories, let $g$ be an oplax monoidal functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$ and let $G$ be a lax monoidal functor from $\mathcal D$ to $\mathcal E$.

Let $F$ be a lax monoidal functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal E$.  Now let $\phi$ be a natural transformation from $F$ to $Gg$ making the following diagrams commute for any objects $x,y$ of $\mathcal C$:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(x)\otimes F(y) @>{\phi_x\otimes\phi_y}>> Gg(x)\otimes Gg(y)\\
@V{m_F}VV @VV{m_G}V \\
 @. G(g(x)\otimes g(y))\\
@V{m_F}VV @AA{G(m_g)}A \\
F(x\otimes y) @>>{\phi_{x\otimes y}}> Gg(x \otimes y)
\end{CD}
$$

$$
\begin{CD}
I_{\mathcal E} @>{\epsilon_G}>> G(I_{\mathcal D}) \\
@V{\epsilon_F}VV @VV{G(\epsilon_g)}V \\
F(I_{\mathcal C}) @>>{\phi_{I_{\mathcal C}}}> Gg(I_{\mathcal C})
\end{CD}
$$

Is there a name for such natural transformations?  I'm tempted to call them *bimonoidal natural transformations*, since they seem to be analogous in some sense to the bifunctors $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}\times\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ that are used in the definition of (co)ends.

*Note:* A special case of this is when $F$ is in fact strong monoidal.  In that case, this is the 'obvious' idea of a monoidal natural transformation from a lax monoidal functor to an oplax monoidal functor.

Comment: *dimonoidal*, or *[extramonoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation)*, if anything :-)

Comment: Can you maybe expand a little the analogy you see with dinatural transformations?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I tried to work out the details, and it didn't quite come out.  The idea was to generalize from $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}\times\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ to morphisms $A^*\otimes A\to B$ in a monoidal category with dual objects, then to generalize from there to the same thing in a bicategory rather than a monoidal category, and lastly to specialize to the case of the 2-category of monoidal categories and lax monoidal functors.  The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a setting in which an oplax monoidal functor coule be regarded as the *dual* of a lax monoidal functor.

Comment: Laxity is not affected by covariance type. If $F : A \to B$ is lax monoidal, and you regard $A,B$ as one-object bicategories, then $F$ will be a lax functor; if $g$ is oplax, then it will be an oplax functor; this does not affect covariance, because if $F$ reverses 1-cells it's simply a lax functor $A^\text{op}\to B$ (you "reverse" 1-cells by redefining $\otimes : (X,Y)\mapsto Y\otimes X$; of course $A^\text{op}\cong A$ if $A$ was symmetric), if it reverses 2-cells it's a lax functor $A^\text{co}\to B$ (A^co now is A^op as 1-category, I hope you get without me fixing the abuse of notation ;) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know a good name for such transformations, but I can give you a reference and some more information about them.  First of all note that more generally you can define a monoidal transformation $f F \to G g$ when $F$ and $G$ are lax monoidal and $f$ and $g$ are colax monoidal.  The axioms then become hexagons (with one side degenerate in the unit case).

Such transformations may seem *ad hoc*, but they actually arise very naturally.  They are the 2-cells in a *double category* whose objects are monoidal categories and whose two kinds of morphism are lax and colax monoidal functors.  This double category was first defined in section 2.2 of [Adjoint for double categories](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_2004__45_3_193_0/) by Grandis and Paré, as a special case of an analogous double category whose objects are *double* categories.

In [Comparing composites of left and right derived functors](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2868) (example 4.8) I observed that an analogous double category can be defined for the algebras over any 2-monad, in which case the corresponding axiom on the 2-cells is that a certain *cube* commutes (the six sides of the hexagons corresponding to the six faces of the cube).

In fact this construction even sits inside something with a universal property: given a 2-category $K$, let $Q(K)$ denote the *triple* category of "quintets", whose objects are those of $K$, whose three kinds of morphisms are all those of $K$, whose three kinds of 2-cells are all 2-cells in $K$ ("quintets"), and whose 3-cells are commutative cubes in $K$.  Any 2-monad on $K$ induces a "triple monad" $Q(T)$ on $Q(K)$, i.e. a monad in the 2-category of triple categories, triple functors, and "transversal" transformations.  The triple category of algebras for $Q(T)$ (i.e. its Eilenberg-Moore object in this 2-category of triple categories) has as its objects $T$-algebras and as its three kinds of morphisms the strict, lax, and colax $T$-morphisms, while its 2-cells relating lax and colax $T$-morphisms are precisely these.

Comment: The nLab article for double categories calls them 'generalized natural transformations', though the Adjoints for Double Categories does not name them.

Comment: @JohnGowers The [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category) says "There is a double category MonCat whose objects are monoidal categories, whose horizontal arrows are lax monoidal functors, whose vertical arrows are colax monoidal functors, and whose 2-cells are *generalized monoidal natural transformations*." [emphasis added]  I don't think this is intended as a definition, merely an observation that they are *a* generalization of monoidal natural transformations.